# Change background on mouse over for default button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, styles

In WPF application I want to change the `BackGround` of my `Button` on `MouseOver`.
The triggers `IsDefault` and `IsMouseOver` are already adjusted. Is it possible to define separate trigger that reacts on both of `IsDefault` and `IsMouseOver` triggers.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsDefault" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1BA1E2" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#9A9EA1" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger ??? Property="IsDefault" Value="True" && Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#9A9E88"/>    
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: It is called [multitrigger](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/multi-triggers-multitrigger-multidatatrigger/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MultiTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multitrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) , [Example of Multi Trigger in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/11879/example-of-multi-trigger-in-wpf.aspx). Like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Multi" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsDefault" Value="True"></Condition>
                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"></Condition>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" ></Setter>
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </Window.Resources>
 <Grid>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource Multi}"></Button>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: But if you use a normal Chrome-Button it's not working as expected.